# Fourier transform of $|2\cos(2x)|$

Tags: fourier-transform

I want to know what is the Fourier transform of $|2\cos(2x)|$

I know how to calculate the Fourier transform of $2\cos(2x)$ but absolute value bothers me.

I write it in another form --> $$|e^{-2ix} + e^{2ix} | $$
but it doesn't help me.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I imagine you are refering to calculating $c(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 e^{inx}2|\cos(2x)\|,dx$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Why 0 to 2pi? No interval specified.

Comment: because $\cos$ is not integrable. You can also consider things in the sense of distributions, but it is not clear from your question.

Comment: @OliverDiaz So there is no problem for me to write the Fourier transform like this? from x = 0 to x = 2*pi? I'm not sure about that. I think it must be from x = -inf to x = inf

Comment: If you are sure that you are talking about the Fourier transform of $\phi(x)=|\cos(2x)|$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and not the Fourier "coefficients" of $\phi$ (or the Fourier transform of $\phi$ as a map on $\mathbb{T}$) then my comments are unncessary.